# How to show a variable before axios petition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a get request where I save the result in a variable called name_student. How can I show this variable in other methods? or how should I declare it?

This is my code:

```
getStudent(){
  axios.get('https://backunizoom.herokuapp.com/student/2')
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data)
        this.name_student=result.data.name
        console.log(name_student)
        
    })
    console.log(name_student)
},
```

Comment: You can declare the variable in `data`. There you can declare as many variables as possible with the initial values set. The variables declared in `data`, which is actually function, can be used in any method functions.

Comment: Yes, but I want the value that you are obtaining with the get request to be saved and I can show it to you in other methods

Comment: Just declare, and set with the value you get from the get request. That value can be used in all other methods.

Comment: Try to do it as you indicate but the variable returns me as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shared data props

As @scar-2018 suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774923/how-to-show-a-variable-before-axios-petition#comment119795020_67774923), you just need to declare `name_student` as a data prop to make the prop available across all component methods and hooks:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name_student: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getStudent() {
      axios.get(/*...*).then((result) => {
        this.name_student = result.data.name

        this.updateStudentName()
      })
    },
    updateStudentName() {
      this.name_student += ' (student)'
    }
  }
}
```

#### Accessing async data

You [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774923/how-to-show-a-variable-before-axios-petition#comment119797840_67774923) that you're seeing `undefined` when you log `name_student`. Assuming the code in your question does not have a typo with regards to the location of the `console.log()` calls, the `axios` callback is run *asynchronously*, and you're logging `this.name_student` *before* `axios` modifies it:

```js
axios.get(/*...*/).then((result) => {
  this.name_student = result.data.name
  console.log(this.name_student) // => 'foo' ✅
})

console.log(this.name_student) // => undefined ❌ (not yet set)
```